# YAML parsing error in Travis CI, but not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, travis-ci, ruby-2.0

I'm using Travis CI for a gem I'm developing and ran into a strange error (links are at the end of the question).

The gem is storing some information serialized with YAML which isn't built manually, but using `YAML.dump` and later loaded again with `YAML.load`.

The following lines are used to dump and load a hash to/from YAML:

```ruby
headers[:ar_mailer_settings] = YAML.dump(settings)
...
ar_settings = YAML.load(mail['ar_mailer_settings'].value)
```

The later line seems to be producing an error on Travis CI, but when I run the tests locally using the same binary versions, everything runs perfectly fine:

```ruby
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 22
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse'
...
/home/travis/build/Stex/ar_mailer_revised/lib/action_mailer/ar_mailer.rb:84:in `deliver!'
```

I put a simple `puts` into the `deliver!` method to see if there would be a difference in the stored values, and it seems that Travis CI is ignoring newlines in the generated YAML which then causes a parse error:

**Travis**:

```ruby
"--- smtp_settings: :address: localhost :port: 25 :domain: localhost.localdomain :user_name: some.user :password: some.password :authentication: :plain :enable_starttls_auto: true "
```

**Locally**:

```ruby
"---\nsmtp_settings:\n  :address: localhost\n  :port: 25\n  :domain: localhost.localdomain\n  :user_name: some.user\n  :password: some.password\n  :authentication: :plain\n  :enable_starttls_auto: true\n"
```

Interestingly, I didn't change anything regarding these methods before the Travis CI was failing, so I'm not sure if I'm simply overlooking something here or if it's some kind of incompatibility issue.

Can I do something to preserve the newline characters?

**Edit: Additional Information**

- The gem allows setting custom SMTP settings and attributes for single email records.
- These can be set directly when generating the email in an ActionMailer::Base instance [see here for a dummy mailer](https://github.com/Stex/ar_mailer_revised/blob/rails_4/test/dummy/app/mailers/test_mailer.rb)
- To transport these custom settings to ActionMailer's `deliver!`-method which actually creates a new email record, I serialize these settings via YAML, save them in the email header temporarily and restore them later see `ar_mailer_setting` and `deliver!` [here](https://github.com/Stex/ar_mailer_revised/blob/rails_4/lib/action_mailer/ar_mailer.rb)

---

The source code which raises the error: [here](https://github.com/Stex/ar_mailer_revised/blob/rails_4/lib/action_mailer/ar_mailer.rb)

The complete Travis CI output: [here](https://travis-ci.org/Stex/ar_mailer_revised/jobs/35812056#L71)

If more information is needed, please let me know and I'll add it to the question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where and how are the `settings` used in `ar_mailer_settings` being generated?  Is it possible that the newlines are being stripped from the original input?

Comment: The settings are set directly in the mailer methods, the above can be found in this [mailer file](https://github.com/Stex/ar_mailer_revised/blob/rails_4/test/dummy/app/mailers/test_mailer.rb) and is used in this [test file](https://github.com/Stex/ar_mailer_revised/blob/rails_4/test/dummy/test/mailers/test_mailer_test.rb).
A link to the file containing the setter methods is at the end of the question